# ASP Guidance - Development on laptop with limited internet access (nonhosted)

Tags: untagged

I am fairly experienced with the .NET family of languages, as well as web development (from a PHP perspective.)

I am home for winter break and have limited internet access but would like to learn ASP using C#.

**Am I able to do development for ASP (and see the results) for free on my laptop (with no internet access), and if so what tools do I need?**

Ideally I'd like to do development in Visual Studio and see the results in my browser via localhost. Extra tools I might need would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/), that should be everything you want.

If you want to do database work, you might want to also install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express (if the Visual Web Developer installer doesn't install it for you).